При запуске ячейки в JupyterLab происходит переход в начало ячейки
При запуске ячейки экран "перепрыгивает" в начало ячейки. При этом, чтобы увидеть результаты выполнения, каждый раз требуется скроллить вниз, что очень неудобно. В ранних версиях JupyterLab такого не было, это плявилось около года назад. Как сделать так, чтобы экран не улетал в начало программного кода ячейки при исполнении?

А вы запускайте ячейку через Shift+Enter, тогда курсор будет в следующую ячейку переходить и вывод будет видно над ней.

Все-таки не то. При большом выводе все равно приходится вручную возаращаться.
